# JSON - Flutter - Loading json list only once

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a code that will fetch data from the FoodData API- https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html
and will display it in a list. I also created a TextField so the user could search for a specific dish.
it all works out well, but I'm having a small problem -

### The list is refreshed every few seconds so the filter list shows for a few seconds, then the list passes to its initial appearance.

I want to make the list load only once and still have the filter feature work just fine.

Here is my code-

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:fit_app/fitness_app_theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<FoodGen>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/list?dataType=Foundation,SR%20Legacy&pageSize=200&api_key=APIKEY');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<FoodGen> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<FoodGen>((json) => FoodGen.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class FoodGen {
  int fdcId;
  String description;
  String dataType;
  String publicationDate;
  String ndbNumber;
  List<FoodNutrients> foodNutrients;

  FoodGen(
      {this.fdcId,
      this.description,
      this.dataType,
      this.publicationDate,
      this.ndbNumber,
      this.foodNutrients});

  FoodGen.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    fdcId = json['fdcId'];
    description = json['description'];
    dataType = json['dataType'];
    publicationDate = json['publicationDate'];
    ndbNumber = json['ndbNumber'];
    if (json['foodNutrients'] != null) {
      foodNutrients = new List<FoodNutrients>();
      json['foodNutrients'].forEach((v) {
        foodNutrients.add(new FoodNutrients.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['fdcId'] = this.fdcId;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['dataType'] = this.dataType;
    data['publicationDate'] = this.publicationDate;
    data['ndbNumber'] = this.ndbNumber;
    if (this.foodNutrients != null) {
      data['foodNutrients'] =
          this.foodNutrients.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class FoodNutrients {
  String number;
  String name;
  dynamic amount;
  String unitName;
  String derivationCode;
  String derivationDescription;

  FoodNutrients(
      {this.number,
      this.name,
      this.amount,
      this.unitName,
      this.derivationCode,
      this.derivationDescription});

  FoodNutrients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    number = json['number'];
    name = json['name'];
    amount = json['amount'];
    unitName = json['unitName'];
    derivationCode = json['derivationCode'];
    derivationDescription = json['derivationDescription'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['number'] = this.number;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    data['unitName'] = this.unitName;
    data['derivationCode'] = this.derivationCode;
    data['derivationDescription'] = this.derivationDescription;
    return data;
  }
}

class FoodPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FoodPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FoodPageState createState() => _FoodPageState();
}

class _FoodPageState extends State<FoodPage> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  List<FoodGen> dishes;
  List<FoodGen> dishesFilter;
  List<FoodGen> duplicateItems;
  List<FoodGen> dummySearchList = List<FoodGen>();

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
  }
  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    if(dishes == null)return;
    dummySearchList.addAll(dishes);
    if(query.isNotEmpty) {
    List<FoodGen> dummyListData = List<FoodGen>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
            String queryLowercase = query.toLowerCase(); 
            if(item.description.toLowerCase().startsWith('$queryLowercase')){
              dummyListData.add(item);
        }
        }
      );
      setState(() {
        dishes.clear();
        dishes.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        dishes.clear();
        dishes.addAll(duplicateItems);
      });
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: FitnessAppTheme.darkBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child:Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),

                onChanged: (value) {
                    filterSearchResults(value);
                },
                controller: editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color:FitnessAppTheme.white),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color:FitnessAppTheme.white), 
                    labelText: "Search",
                    hintText: "Search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
              ),

            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<FoodGen>>(
                future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  dishes = snapshot.data;
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? ListView.builder(
 
                        itemCount: dishes.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: ListTile(title: Text(dishes[index].description))
                          );   
                        },
                      )
                      : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help here (:

Answer (score 0):

Just place `fetchPhotos` in class variable and use it in `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
var photosRequest;

@override
void initState() {
  photosRequest = fetchPhotos(client);
}
```

And in `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
builder: photosRequest.then((photos) => filterSearchResults(photos)),
```

If you calling `Future` from variable and variable cannot changes `FutureBuilder` cannot call it again and use data that fetched previously.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to initialize the dishes list with the JSON data in the initState void once, use it in the FutureBuilder and filter it with the filter function. How can I do that? @fartem

Comment: You can pass filter parameters to `fetchPhotos` and filter items each time you changed filter parameter.

Comment: could u show me how to do that? I'm not sure I understood @fartem

Comment: Another exception was thrown: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<FoodGen>>) => Widget' @fartem

Comment: You should return `List<FoodGen>` from `filterSearchResults` and use only one list to work with all and sorted items. By default you have a loaded data that stored in a list, after you filtered it, you need to change original list and show data again from it.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Provider Package And `Listen: false` , This Will Call Once,

Here is the Example With This Package Hope it will help you .

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^4.3.3



import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

/// This is a reimplementation of the default Flutter application using provider + [ChangeNotifier].

void main() {
  runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

/// Mix-in [DiagnosticableTreeMixin] to have access to [debugFillProperties] for the devtool
// ignore: prefer_mixin
class Counter with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Makes `Counter` readable inside the devtools by listing all of its properties
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(IntProperty('count', count));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),

            /// Extracted as a separate widget for performance optimization.
            /// As a separate widget, it will rebuild independently from [MyHomePage].
            ///
            /// This is totally optional (and rarely needed).
            /// Similarly, we could also use [Consumer] or [Selector].
            Count(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        key: const Key('increment_floatingActionButton'),

        /// Calls `context.read` instead of `context.watch` so that it does not rebuild
        /// when [Counter] changes.
        onPressed: () => context.read<Counter>().increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Count extends StatelessWidget {
  const Count({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(

        /// Calls `context.watch` to make [Count] rebuild when [Counter] changes.
        '${context.watch<Counter>().count}',
        key: const Key('counterState'),
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you implement it in my script? @Tasnuva oshin